# SignalR from Application Server (.NET) to Web Server (.NET) and Web Server to clients (JS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr

We had a fairly big system running, using **SignalR** for 'real-time' updates on map, charts, and simple entity views as well. This application had it's business login in the same server to which clients connected through Javascript (the basic SignalR connection story). The business logic triggered events on our hub classes to inform clients about changes through static hub context.
In my hub classes:

```c#
    public static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

    public static void Static_NotifySomething(string something) {
        ...
        hubContext.Clients.All.notifySomething(something);
        ...
    }
```

And my back-end code called these methods when needed. (i.e: when location update comes in, or business logic changes state of something)

As time passed we needed to re-structure our system into Application Server and Web Server, but still keeping the 'real-time' updates.
I thought it would be good to keep the existing updating structure, but I can't let my clients to get to the Application Server from Javascript, they connect to the Web Server now. However the business logic invoked state changes are still happening in the Application Server.

**The solution so far**

I have a SignalR connection between Application Server (.NET) to Web Server (.NET), where the Web Server is the client, looking for the events invoked in the back-end. Grabs the events coming in, and calling it's own Hub classes where he is the server and sending to the connected Javascript clients (here the basic SignalR connection story again).

In my hub proxy:

```c#
    public async void SignalRConnectionListener() {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://applicationServer.com");

        IHubProxy myHubNotificationProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        // rest ...

        myHubNotificationProxy.On<string>("notifySomething", something => {
            MyHubInWebServer.Static_NotifySomething(something);
        });

        // rest ... 

        await hubConnection.Start();
    }
```

With this I barely had to change something, I have a so-to-say duplication of the hub classes and one additional proxy class, which starts his async method on application startup.
As first option I hosted the .NET client in a Windows Service, but that just gives me more trouble with maintenance. I would prefer if I can keep this inside the Web Server application unless there is some serious drawback.

Now this means I am running a thread in the Web Server looking for the Application Server events. Is that a bad idea? Is there a better solution to solve this? The applications are hosted in IIS in both servers. 
I normal cases (GET, POST) Web Server is sending requests to Application Server through WCF. I imagine we will have multiple Web Servers in the future.

**UPDATE**

It does work with multiple web servers. I am still not sure if this is the best solution. It is also not too easy to debug the connections.

Comment: If I understand your design right, your bottleneck for scalability will be your single active signalR connection between the Web server and the application server which is used to convey notification change messages. What if you have a constantly growing number of users? Your single connection can only propagate the messages so fast. You will also need to handle concurrency better. All notifications from all connections on one server funnel into one connection to the other server. This might be a problem if you have a lot of notifications.